# designing an ontology semantic web

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

I'm trying to design an ontology and i'm forced to use SEMFacet as a part of the project.

SemFacet is an open source search engine that is built over Semantic web technology it works as follow i create an ontology using protege and i upload it to SemFacet and i start searching my ontology.

My ontology has courses and a predicate that describes what these courses are about. So for example let's suppose i have an individual course CS101 that is instantiated from courses class. The course class has a data-object property called description its type is `xsd^^string`.

My problem is that whenever the predicate *i.e. description property* is preceded by a URI "Imaginary URI" SemFacet can't find what i'm taking about. But if i remove the URI everything seems to work just fine.

I told my professor about the issue, he told me that because you are using a URI that does not exist. to be honest i'm not convinced about using a URI that does not exist.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, SEMFacet does not support [blank nodes](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-blank-nodes) (that's a proper name for "imaginary URIs") correctly.

Unless SEMFacet tries to resolve the resources pointed by the URI, you don't need to create a live URI (i.e. the one with HTTP 200 OK response), but only a valid one.

Make sure that you don't leave empty IRIs in Protégé.

Answer (score 0):

@berezovskiy I think OP did not mean blank nodes with imaginary URIs but he meant URIs which he created himself and do not exist like : http://mysuperfancyuri.com

So maybe your professor just wants you to be more standard conform and use already existing predicates instead of creating your own ones. You could for example look at dcterms:description (http://purl.org/dc/terms/description) for a description predicate.

Comment: Well this idea won't work... Simply because let's assume i want to create my own ontology my own vocabulary There are no standards exist that describe my own vocabulary, so i need to create my own standards in a way or another.. Well after all i've already delivered the project. But thanks for the help man :)

Comment: So what was the solution in the end? Is the program really that bad that it can't handle non-existing URIs?

Comment: It can handle them but it needs lots of configurations.. But in my opinion this software is bad, and i think someone might build a better software than semFacet. Well i'm gonna do it but not in the current time.